# how to pass variables in url with an ID section using PHP?

Tags: php, variables, parameter-passing, urlvariables

I can do this:

```
<a href="home.php?var=home">home</a>
```

But when I have a link with an Id, I can't pass variables:

```
<a href="home.php#sectionID?var=home">home</a> <--!this doesn't work of course -->
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.location.hash` in javascript

```
<script>alert(window.location.hash);</script>
```

And the `parse_url()` function in PHP

```
<?php echo parse_url("home.php?var=home#sectionID",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);?>
```

your HTML will be..

```
<a href="home.php?var=home#sectionID">home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP you can not use '#' in the URL, it will not be passed to the server.

You can use urlencode in order to encode the non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable with $home dollar sign, i think you getting confused with JavaScript variable and PHP. To retrieve the variable values on a new page use $_GET['ID'].

Hope this helps.